# Slicer not affecting group by table in Power BI visual

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerquery

I am relatively new to power bi so this might be more difficult to me. I have two tables in Power BI one is a general table with status of an order its ID and its date. The second one was created by referencing and grouping then adding a count aggregation. When i try to use the date slider in my visual the matrix is not changing because the date is not included in the second table.

Table 1 :

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New | 01/01/2022 |
| 2 | Completed | 08/31/2021 |
| 3 | Under Review | 09/23/2021 |
| 4 | New | 10/11/2019 |

Table 2(referenced then grouped by status and returns counting in different rows:

| Status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| New | 2 |
| Under review | 1 |
| Completed | 1 |

When i try to use the date slider although the group by table is referenced to the main one the data in the visual is not changed. It seems to be because the date is not in the group by table but i am not sure how exactly to tackle this situation

Comment: Have you joined them?

Comment: How would i join a summary table and the information table

Comment: Honestly, I see no point of the 2nd table.

Comment: The table is used to create a calculate a total percentage calculated column that would be displayed on the table

Comment: Which is something you can do in an measure, in the first table, correct?